# Render Material UI icons as marker in Highcharts

Tags: angular, highcharts, material-ui

I am looking to render Material UI icons as markers. Could not find any clear documentation how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that in the current implementation marker could be changed to **graphic.url** or **custom SVG symbol**, meanwhile Material UI, in the way you want to use, shares a function which changes the font to wanted symbol.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.marker.symbol

I am aware that Material UI shares also an SVG icon, but their customization to fit in Highcharts is not easy. Take a look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-symbol/ and see how the cross is rendered:

```
return ['M', x, y, 'L', x + w, y + h, 'M', x + w, y, 'L', x, y + h, 'z'];
```

Where x and y are a point coordinates - that renders different path values for each point.

Here is my attempt of using the materialUI SVGIcon from this [example](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#semantic-svg-icons):

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j2Lq4kgp/

I defined this symbol as it is in the materialUI API and later positioned it by using this function:

```
events: {
    render(){ 
      let chart = this;
                
      chart.series[0].points.forEach(p => {
      console.log(p.graphic)
        p.graphic.translate(p.plotX - chart.marginRight - 2, p.plotY - p.graphic.getBBox().height + 2)
      })
      
    }
  }
```

But to be honest I am not sure about this method...

I think that you should consider using fontAwasome. Highcharts allows custom pattern to use them, see: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/2A7Zf/